# confusing about oracle when accessing data

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

First i want to explain what i have done with my oracle,
i use oracle XE in my win7x64.

i have 3 file contained '*insert into ..*' query ..

file 1.sql is about 3MB in inserted by Oracle SQL Developer
file 2.sql is about 30MB in inserted by Oracle SQL Developer
file 3.sql is about 120MB and cannot be inserted by Oracle SQL Developer so i use SQLPlus (@3.sql)

the problem is,
i only see data *1.sql* and *2.sql* instead data *3.sql* when i open my **Oracle SQL Developer**.
then i only see data *3.sql* instead *1.sql* and *2.sql* when i login from **SQL Plus**.

what should i do to see my all data inserterd?

i only connect to this XE in my local laptop ..

Need your suggestion :D

== **SOLVED** ==

i miss commit on both *Oracle SQL Developer* and *SQL Plus*
 1. commit in Oracle SQL Developer using F11
 2. commit in SQL Plus just happening when you type 'exit' or 'quit'

Comment: do you perform a commit after inserts?

Comment: now, i can see all from **SQL Plus** after doing commit in **Oracle SQL Developer**, but i still cannot see 3.sql in my **Oracle SQL Developer** since 3.sql is inserted by **SQL Plus**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have 3 files containing a bunch of INSERT statements, and imported file1.sql and file2.sql using Oracle SQL Developer and file3.sql using SQL/Plus.

- What is the output of SQLPlus after running @file3.sql?
- Did you do a commit in SQLPlus after importing the data?
- What query did you run in SQL Developer afterwards to check whether file3.sql was imported?

Comment: answer:
**1**. in SQL plus i see the output : **1 row created**
**2**. i don't do this .. how to commit in SQL Plus, i just read tutorial to usu @*.sql?
**3**. i just click on the table and the data is blank

Comment: i just know that we have to commit in SQL plus, since i only get the syntax to do something, but it's not explained to commit. **Commit automatically happen when we type 'exit'**, this one i miss since i immeadiatly close the console :D